# How to disable hit test on views that are outside the frame due to offset in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am using a Paged Stack that scrolls horizontally and snaps to the selected index. The functionality works fine unless I have it alongside another view. When I scroll, the offset is blocking the view.

I have omitted .clipped() just so it can be visualized. If I add it, it looks visually fine but it is still interact-able, blocking gestures intended for the view below it.

```
struct PagedStack<Content: View>: View {
let pageCount: Int
let spacing: CGFloat
@Binding var currentIndex: Int
let content: Content

@GestureState private var translation: CGFloat = 0

init(pageCount: Int, spacing: CGFloat, currentIndex: Binding<Int>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
    self.pageCount = pageCount
    self.spacing = spacing
    self._currentIndex = currentIndex
    self.content = content()
}

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        HStack(spacing: self.spacing) {
            self.content.frame(width: geometry.size.width)
        }
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, alignment: .leading)
        .offset(x: -CGFloat(self.currentIndex) * (geometry.size.width + self.spacing))
        .offset(x: self.translation)
        .animation(.interactiveSpring())
        .gesture(
            DragGesture().updating(self.$translation) { value, state, _ in
                state = value.translation.width
            }.onEnded { value in
                let offset = value.translation.width / geometry.size.width
                let newIndex = (CGFloat(self.currentIndex) - offset).rounded()
                self.currentIndex = min(max(Int(newIndex), 0), self.pageCount - 1)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

}

Here is the visual:
[image]

Comment: The existence of the .clipped() function was useful to me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I added .contentShape(Rectangle()) to make the hit test area limited to the frame.